# Passing bean from one JSF page to another

Tags: jsf

I am working on a project of a simple reservation system.

In Netbeans, I've created some JSF pages, with the index.xhtml having a  inside the  with a var="room".

When I execute roomInfo(room), I get the second JSF page with the information about the room.

The second JSF page only has a  inside the  instead of a  where I can set a "var". I also have a button that executes a update on the database with some user input.

My problem is that I can't pass the bean from the index.xhtml to the roomInfo.xhtml, so when I execute the java code to update the database it's null.

```
room.setCheckIn(roomBean.getCheckIn());
```

Comment: Please, re-read your question, there is code not visible. And you don't run a jsf app in Netbeans, netbeans is an IDE. And for passing things from one page to another Stackoverflow already contains Q/A. Please try to find them (excluding netbeans in the search helps!)

Comment: If you are using a desktop browser, check "Related" in the right column on this page -->